# Call Yeoman commands from a NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, yeoman

How to call a Yeoman command from a NodeJS server?

I want to make a simple client webpage which allows me to execute Yeoman commands, on the NodeJS server, such as

```
yeoman install angular
yeoman server
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a path or a websocket command which executes this sample code:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var yeoman = spawn('yeoman', ['install', 'angular']);
yeoman.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('yeoman: ' + data);
});
```

Later edit:
You have several options + examples here, including `exec` suggested in the comments:
http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: using exec would be simpler `var exec = require('child_process').exec; exec('yeoman install angular', function(err, stdout) { console.log('yeoman', stdout); });`

Answer (score 1):

var env = require('yeoman-generator')();

var workingDirectory = //Path where generator should be executed.
generator = env.create('iosapp:app');
generator.destinationRoot(workingDirectory);
generator.run();

Generator ID for create call you will be able to find by calling yo without arguments.